# Android XMPP File Transfer

Tags: android, xmpp

I'm newbie to Android programming. I'm trying to develop messenger application with file transfer feature. But having difficulties reagrding file transfer.

`viewer.java**`

```
Button transfer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnimage);    
transfer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);                
            }
        });

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                    XMPPClient.getInstance().SendFile(to, selectedImagePath);
                }
            }
        }

        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
```

and then i Have XMPPCLIENT.java

```
public void ReceiveFile() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager
                        .getInstanceFor(getConnection());

                if (sdm == null)
                    sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(getConnection());

                sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");

                sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");

                // Create the file transfer manager
                final FileTransferManager managerListner = new FileTransferManager(
                        getConnection());

                FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(getConnection(), true);

                Log.i("File transfere manager", "created");

                // Create the listener
                managerListner
                        .addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
                            public void fileTransferRequest(
                                    final FileTransferRequest request) {

                                Log.i("Recieve File",
                                        "new file transfere request  new file transfere request   new file transfere request");

                                Log.i("file request",
                                        "from" + request.getRequestor());

                                IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request
                                        .accept();

                                Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog", "accepted");
                                try {

                                    transfer.recieveFile(new File("/sdcard/"
                                            + request.getFileName()));

                                    while (!transfer.isDone()
                                            || (transfer.getProgress() < 1)) {

                                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                                        Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog",
                                                "still receiving : "
                                                        + (transfer
                                                                .getProgress())
                                                        + " status "
                                                        + transfer.getStatus());

                                        if (transfer.getStatus().equals(
                                                Status.error)) {
                                            // Log.i("Error file",
                                            // transfer.getError().getMessage());
                                            Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog",
                                                    "cancelling still receiving : "
                                                            + (transfer
                                                                    .getProgress())
                                                            + " status "
                                                            + transfer
                                                                    .getStatus());
                                            transfer.cancel();

                                            break;
                                        }

                                    }

                                } catch (XMPPException e) {

                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    public void SendFile(final String Receiver, final String Directory) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

            ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager
            .getInstanceFor(getConnection());
            if (sdm == null)
                sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(getConnection());
            sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
            sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
            // Create the file transfer manager
            FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(
                    mConnection);
            FileTransferNegotiator
            .setServiceEnabled(getConnection(), true);

            // Create the outgoing file transfer
            OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager
            .createOutgoingFileTransfer(getJIDofUserID(Receiver));
            sendMessage(getJIDofUserID(Receiver), "image");
            Log.i("transfere file", "outgoingfiletransfere is created");
            try {
                OutgoingFileTransfer.setResponseTimeout(30000);
                transfer.sendFile(new File(Directory), "Description");
                Log.i("transfere file", "sending file");
                while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Log.i("transfere file", "sending file status "
                                + transfer.getStatus() + "progress: "
                                + transfer.getProgress());
                        if (transfer.getStatus() == org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.error) {
                            transfer.cancel();
                            Log.e("",transfer.getError()+" error");
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaa"+e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaa"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("transfere file", "sending file done");
        }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

So my questions are:

1. Is connection that i use is the same connection as chatting (default port: 5222)?
2. When I trigger `sendfile(final String Receiver, final String Directory)` function, when and how the receiver get any notification?

Comment: new FileTransferManager(connection);
what connection is required in this parameter,,, xmppConnection default or with certain properties ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. That depends on which method is used for file transfer. XMPP knows several. You can read more about it here https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-XMPP-File-Transfer and http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/
2. The receiving entity always has to confirm the file transfer first. But it depends on the other client how this is implemented e.g. if there is a pop-up windows saying that there is an incoming file transfer. It is also possible that the client on the other side is configured to auto-accept all requests.

Answer (score 0):

First add following configuration in to your xmpp configuration class.

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider('query','http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams', new BytestreamsProvider());
2
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider('query','http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items', new DiscoverItemsProvider());
3
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider('query','http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info', new DiscoverInfoProvider());
```

Then add or edit following three properties in open fire server.

1. xmpp.proxy.enabled – true
2. xmpp.proxy.port – 7777
3. xmpp.proxy.externalip – [publicly accessible host or ip]

please make these changes and try again .